# Unable to boot Ubuntu 16.04 after update and windows boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

I'm currently dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04.

Because my ubuntu didn't start, I went on fresh install, everything was ok.

I then updated all drivers and stuff, setup my machine, installed my softwares and everything was good at that point (notice that I disabled mouse acceleration, not sure this can cause problems there).

After that, I rebooted on windows, did nothing too fancy and booted back to ubuntu. At that point, fast boot and hibernation settings were still on.

However, ubuntu refused to start hanging on either a black screen or just a single cleaning line.

I tried several methods found on internet related to grub starting option, recovery mode, graphics driver etc.

Both /var/log/boot and dmesg show no error so I'm really stuck there.

What should I provide to get some help ? I'm totally lost on this one and don't even know where to look.

Comment: You state, "fast boot and hibernation settings were still on." Both Fast Boot and Hibernation are incompatible with dual boot, particularly hibernation. In Windows, open CMD as admin, type *powercfg -h off*, then *shutdown /s /t 0" to perform a full shutdown. Boot to Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I might not have been clear enough, but those settings were already disabled on windows. It's one of the solution I tried but it might have broke ubuntu ? Should I go for yet another reinstall ?

Comment: Since there's not enough information to find the cause of the issue, reinstallation, following directions precisely, is probably the easiest. Once you get a working dual-boot system, make an image so you can go back to it should something go bad.